# No table south_migrationhistory

Tags: django

I'm trying to use social-auth in django with a Mac Maverick.

This is my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'social_auth',
    'south',
)
```

When I run

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

I get this

```
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin

Not synced (use migrations):
 - social_auth
 - south
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

So, when I try to migrate social-auth with

```
python mange.py migrate social_auth
```

I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: south_migrationhistory
```

When I try

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get this traceback

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 200, in migrate_app
    applied_all = check_migration_histories(applied_all, delete_ghosts, ignore_ghosts)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 79, in check_migration_histories
    for h in histories:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 96, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 450, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: south_migrationhistory
```

What should I do?

Comment: After including south did you run syncdb ?

Comment: Is south in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: I updated my question with your comments. south is in INSTALLED_APPS and I tried to run syncdb.

Comment: SOmething is wrong. `south` should not be in `migrations`. Just try `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Ok. I get this message: no such table: south_migrationhistory (I updated my question with the traceback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `lib/python2.7/site-packages/south` check if you have a folder `migrations`. Delete them. That solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but my /usr/lib/python2.7 doesn't contain a directory for site-packages. I did install South. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: This directory differs based on install & if you're using something like virtualenv. Use this to find it 'import site; site.getsitepackages()'

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `schemamigration` command before your `migrate`. Try:

```
python manage.py schemamigration social_auth --initial
```

or

```
python manage.py schemamigration social_auth --auto
```

before running the `migrate` command.